# How to replace data in cell, based on Len(cell) in smart table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code below. I need to delete/replace data with condition: 
1) if Len(cell) = 1 and 2) only in specific columns? Can you please support me?
Thanks you.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim xWs As Worksheet

        For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If xWs.Name = "SheetTest" Then
                For Each lo In xWs.ListObjects
                    For Each lc In lo.ListColumns
                        If lc.Name Like "Week starting" & "*" Then
                            For Each cell In lc.DataBodyRange
                                If Len(cell.Value) = 1 Then
                                    cell.Replace What:="A", Replacement:=""
                                    cell.Replace What:="S", Replacement:=""
                                End If
                            Next cell
                        End If
                    Next lc
                Next lo
            End If
        Next xWs
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't loop cell-by-cell: `lc.DataBodyRange.Replace What:="A", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole`.

Comment: The [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) docs are helpful.

Comment: @BigBen, its correct, but I have + another condition. I need to consider only cell if Len(cell) = 2 for example. How to do that?